# Microsoft Word missing dictate functionality

Tags: microsoft-word

Word is supposed to have a dictate / transcribe button on the right side of the ribbon, but it does not for me (this is for Version 2112 Build 14729.20260 on Windows 10 Pro which I believe is the latest).  I ran check for updates in Word after doing everything below, and it says I'm up to date.

I think this may be associated with a paid Microsoft 365 subscription so I signed up for the $7/mo one which then allowed me to use Word online to access the dictate functionality but not my local desktop app.

I confirmed I was signed in with that account and even signed out and back in and restarted after signing up for the subscription but no luck.

I also tried starting in safe mode and it wasn't there then (as some people online said other add-ins could conflict).

I checked the customize ribbon section and can't even find anything to do with dictation or transcription listed under "All Commands".

Separately, I tried to use the Word online dictate functionality and after signing up it does allow me to use it (whereas before it said I needed to pay).  The problem with this as a good alternative is it can't handle long transcriptions well - I just mention to validate that I should have access.

Comment: When you look under All commands, do you see voice or not? If it is there, then add it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio it doesn't show there for me in all commands.  It goes from "Visual Basic Editor" to "Watermark" in the alphabetical list of commands.

Comment: Try repairing and/or removing and re-installing Office.

Comment: Your 365 subscription allows you to download the desktop version of Word. Have you done that? Dictate may show up in a Voice group on the Ribbon. As far as I know, Transcribe is only available in the browser/free version of Word.

Comment: Transcription is also limited to 300 minutes per month.